# Fixed Zoom Extend For Overview Map on ArcGIS Server JavaScript API 3.8

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can some one please let me know if it is possible to have the Map Overview with Fixed extend and none zoom in or out functions? I know this was not possible on v.3 but how about v3.8?

Comment: If you want a static overview map, perhaps you could just embed it as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

You can disable navigation for the entire map like so:

```
map.disableMapNavigation();
```

But the problem with disabling map navigation for the MapOverview when you create your overview map, the code is binding all these events from the main map (zoom-end, pan...).  I don't there is a clear way to identify these events so that you could disconnect them.  If ESRI would provide the source code for their API, it would make figuring it out easier...

```
//Create Map
var map = esri.Map(...)

//Create Dijit
var overviewMapDijit = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({
    map: map, //references main map
    attachTo: "bottom-right",
    color:" #D84E13",
    opacity: .40
});

overviewMapDijit.startup(); //overview map does not exist until you show it..
overviewMapDijit.show();

//Here's what we would need to do...
//Find all events that were connected to main map
//Disconnect these events
//Disable map navigation for overviewMapDijit.overviewMap
```

So, for my final answer...

No, this cannot be done easily and is not a default part of the API.  Hopefully they will release their source code, because simple things like this are a pain with their API.

Comment: Does this help answer your question at all?